# Rreplacing multiple versions of a person's name with just one?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset for which the rows are information about conference papers: year, title, list of authors (all fields are strings; authors are delimited with commas). For example:

```
Year    Title                                              Author(s)
'2011'  'I watched all the Simpsons episodes in one week'  'Ludwig van Beethoven, Joseph Haydn, Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart'
```

I'm trying to clean up this dataset so that it can be turned into an online searchable database. The trouble is that a single name may appear in a multitude of forms:

- `Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart`,
- `Wolfgang A. Mozart`,
- `W. A. Mozart`,
- `Mr Wolfgang A. Mozart`,
- `W. A. Mozart (Austria)`

and so on. I need to choose just one name from all the alternatives, and replace all the other alternatives with that chosen name. Is there an easy way to do this?

I'm assuming it will be some sort of string replace, as in:

```
names = ['Wolfgang A. Mozart','W. A. Mozart','Mr Wolfgang A. Mozart','W. A. Mozart (Austria)']
for n in names:
    db['Authors'] = db['Authors'].str.replace(n,'Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart', regex=True)
```

I'm wondering if this is very clumsy, and if there might be a better, more vectorized way.

Comment: How do you know which names are related? ie how do you know that all those names are for one single person?

Comment: Good point - but it's usually pretty obvious by either a small change (initial for middle name) plus topic of articles.  Otherwise I leave the name unchanged.

Comment: To you a small change is *obvious* to the eye. But not to a computer. Unless you have a list of names thaat you know are related to a particular name, there is no well established method to determine the relationship. eg notice that even one letter will make two names to be different people  `Jane Smith` and the sister `Janet Smith`. Obviously two people. But just 1 letter difference.

Comment: That's why I went laboriously through all the "doubled-up" names and checked them by hand.  Mostly the issue was an initial sometimes being used, sometimes not.  There are difficulties with some naming systems; for example Malaysian names may or may not include the patronymic "Bin" or "Binti" (or their abbreviations), and "Mohammed" may be shortened to "Mohd" or "Md".   Chinese and Korean names being generally short and similar I mostly left alone.  (Are "Hsiao-Chia Lee", "Hsiao-Chi Lee", "Hsiao-Cha Lee" the same or different people?  And who is "H.-C. Lee"?)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have an exaustive list of the forms a name can appears in, one solution is to create a dict with all possible mappings to fix all authors names:

```
names = ['W. A. Mozart (Austria)', 'Mr Wolfgang A. Mozart', 'Wolfgang A. Mozart', 'W. A. Mozart']
fix_names_dict = dict.fromkeys(names, 'Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart')
df['Authors'] = df['Authors'].apply(
    lambda names: ', '.join(
        fix_names_dict.get(name, name)
        for name in names.split(', ')
    )
)
```

Another approach if you don't have an exaustive list with possible forms of the same name, but do have a list of correct names is to use [Fuzzy matching](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz)

```
from thefuzz import process
all_correct_names = ['Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart', 'Ludwig van Beethoven', 'Joseph Haydn']
df['Authors'] = df['Authors'].apply(
    lambda names: ', '.join(
        process.extractOne(name, all_correct_names)[0]
        for name in names.split(', ')
    )
)
```

You can combine both approaches in a smart way:

1. Create a dict with your guesses about the forms a signle name can
   have.
2. Use fuzzy matching to choose the closest form to the found name.
3. Use the initial mapping to find the correct form.

code:

```
fix_names_dict = {
    **dict.fromkeys(['Mr Wolfgang A. Mozart', 'W. A. Mozart'], 'Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart'),
    **dict.fromkeys(['Mr L van Beethoven', 'Ludwig van Beethoven'], 'Ludwig van Beethoven'),
}
# the keys are all the wrong forms you specified manually
wrong_forms = list(fix_names_dict)
df['Authors'] = df['Authors'].apply(
    lambda names: ', '.join(
        fix_names_dict[process.extractOne(name, wrong_forms)[0]]
        for name in names.split(', ')
    )
)
```

You can consider some shortcuts if you care about performance:

- If the name is already correct, i.e exsists in the dict values, leave
  it without further processing.
- If the name exists exactly as it is in the keys, get the value
  directly without fuzzy matching.

and to optimize your chances of matching, include also the correct form of the name, just if it happens that the name in your dataframe is closer to its correct form than any other form you've specified by hand in the dict.

Applying all of this gives:

```
fix_names_dict = {
    **dict.fromkeys(['Mr Wolfgang A. Mozart', 'W. A. Mozart'], 'Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart'),
    **dict.fromkeys(['Mr L van Beethoven', 'Ludwig van Beethoven'], 'Ludwig van Beethoven'),
}
correct_names = set(fix_names_dict.values())
# match also using the correct form of the name
for correct_name in correct_names:
    fix_names_dict[correct_name] = correct_name
all_forms = list(fix_names_dict)

def optimized_name_fix(name: str):
    # either it exists in the exact form you specified in the dict
    # or the name is already correct.
    maybe_fixed_name = fix_names_dict.get(name)
    if maybe_fixed_name is not None:
        return maybe_fixed_name
    closest_match = process.extractOne(name, all_forms)[0]
    return fix_names_dict[closest_match]

df['Authors'] = df['Authors'].apply(
    lambda names: ', '.join(map(optimized_name_fix, names.split(', ')))
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much - that looks much better than my own clumsy solution.   I've made a list based on last names.  And I am making educated guesses whether the names refer to the same or to different people (Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart = Wolfgang A. Mozart; William Albert Mozart is different; W. A. Mozart could be either so leave unchanged unless I can guess based on the topic of the articles.)

Comment: @Alasdair You're welcome, I've added a second approach where you don't have to specify a full list of all possible forms of a name. Feel free to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: You can exlude the cases where you see a chance of confusion from the dict. Then handle them specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have a list of names and how you want them to be replaced. Here is an example

```
names = [['Wolfgang A. Mozart','W. A. Mozart',
         'Mr Wolfgang A. Mozart','W. A. Mozart (Austria)'],
         ["Mohammed", "Mohd",  "Md", 'Moha']] 

to = ['Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart', 'Mohammed']           

dc = {k:j for i, j in zip(names, to) for k in i}


df = pd.DataFrame(['Ludwig van Beethoven, Joseph Haydn',
                   'Md, W. A. Mozart','Wolfgang A. Mozart,Moha'], 
                  columns=['names'])

repl = lambda x: dc.get(s := x.group(1), s)

df['replaced'] = df.names.str.replace("\\b([^,]+)", repl, regex=True)

                               names                            replaced
0  Ludwig van Beethoven, Joseph Haydn  Ludwig van Beethoven, Joseph Haydn
1                    Md, W. A. Mozart   Mohammed, Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart
2             Wolfgang A. Mozart,Moha    Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart,Mohammed
```